# Is it possible to call a generic dll/so shared library from Mathematica

Tags: librarylink

In Python, there's something called [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes). With ctypes, one can call any shared library function and get the results back to your script. It supports all kinds of C-language types, such as int, double, long, struct, etc...

Is this possible with Mathematica too? Is there a full example on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, at least on Windows you can do this with .NET/Link.  I don't know if it also works on other platforms.  .NET/Link does, but it might be more trouble to set up and I do not know if this specific functionality is supported.

Comment: Related, perhaps even duplicate?: [(22679)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22679/121)

Comment: Here's how to do it: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/NETLink/tutorial/CallingNETFromTheWolframLanguage.html#32076

Comment: @Szabolcs Would be disappointing if it's only for windows... because I do all my tough calculations on Linux.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would compare this with Python's C API, not ctypes. Because with C API you need to import some python headers, which is similar to what's given in the question there. The nice thing about `ctypes` is that you can write a native interface without requiring to import any non-native header from Python. This would be great if available for Mathematica!

Comment: Here's info on how to do it: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8443/12  Here's info on how to use NET/Link on Unix: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20765/running-net-link-on-mono-on-macos-or-any-unix-or-linux-distro  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1967/using-net-4-0-from-netlink/1968#1968  You could consider rephrasing the question and asking specifically about `DefineDLLFuntcion` on non-Windows platforms.  Please try it out and if it works, do still post your own answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! However the unix link only executes a program. It doesn't use a DLL/SO file. It seems this is not supported in linux.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I'm not sure what you mean.  Did you get NET/Link working on your platform already?  If you did, did you test `DefineDLLFuntcion`?

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't use Windows for programming, so I can't test it. I need a unix example with linking to some `so` file, like `libc.so.6`, as you see in the examples of `ctypes`. That's the simplest and minimal working example. Right?

Comment: What I am trying to tell you is that you can *probably* do this on Linux.  But *you* have to try if it works.  You have all the examples to follow: I gave you a link on how to get NET/Link working on Linux with Mono.  That's the first thing you have to do.  Second, read up on how to load shared libraries with NET/Link (the other link I have you), and try if that method also works on Linux. It *probably* does.

Comment: @Szabolcs OK. I'll try it on linux. If it works, I'll post it here as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I should not that when I tried to get NET/Link working on Mac last time, I wasn't successful.  So there may be obstacles.  But I didn't put much effort into it.  While all the steps to achieve this should be in the links I gave you, putting them together successfully in practice may not be trivial, so it will be very useful if you post your experience.  This may also be useful: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: Try Java link in Wolfram, then JNA or JNI to get from Java (or, better, Clojure) to the metal.  I've done it. Takes a little work but screams for speed.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Would be great if you post a working example here :)

Comment: I've probably lost it. I was toying with factorization and deep zoom. I think I started here: https://github.com/kframework/mpfr-java but most of it worked with little drama.