# Is there a way to run Python from within Mathematica?

Tags: interoperability, python

I know there is some support for running *Mathematica* from Python, but is there any way to do the reverse. For example, to import some Python classes and use them in *Mathematica*?

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1894/5 (I don't know enough to tell if it's a dupe or not)

Comment: @rm-rf: Different: that relies on .NET.

Comment: use them how? what sort of thing would you like to do?

Comment: I've given some answers where a Python script was assembled and then executed from within a notebook: [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1147/245) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4903/245)

Comment: @acl: Example: I have access to a library of classes written (by someone else, for example something like [astropy](http://www.astropy.org)) in Python that and I'd like to be able to "import" those classes and then call them from within Mathematica.

Comment: Google Pythonika

Comment: @MarkMcClure I think Pythonika is the reverse of the reverse, and he's only asking for the reverse...

Comment: @Jens He says he wants "to import some Python classes and use them in Mathematica". That's *exactly* what Pythonika does. I've used it to run sage from Mathematica. One of the dumbest things I've ever done, but I did it: http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/Mathematica/Sage/

Comment: @MarkMcClure You're right, I think that's an excellent answer then.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: Pythonica seems not to be a viable solution. I can't get it to load (0S X 10.8.2, Python 2.7.2, *Mathematica* 9.0). Are there any alternatives?

Comment: This Pythonika link is no longer valid? https://sites.google.com/site/erocarrera/pythonika.html

Comment: Pythonika doesn't work with version 10.x

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since 11.2 Mathematica has supported [`ExternalEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) and since 11.3 this functionality has been conveniently available simply by beginning an input cell with `>` which produces an external code cell:

[image]

The output of these cells is a Wolfram Language expression that you can then compute with.

Comment: Please clarify with an example, say, for Python, including when Python is not the default OS system installation but another, e.g., anaconda's.

Comment: @murray: Was that the OP's question?

Comment: No, but it certainly would be helpful.

Comment: But it seems that Mathematica complains when you try to import some python packages?

Comment: You may have to [configure python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html) by calling the `RegisterExternalEvaluators[]` function and supplying a path to your executable

Answer (score 20):

Building off of @M.R.'s idea, it is possible to set up an interactive python shell using `StartProcess` as opposed to `RunProcess`, allowing for much more flexible connectivity between Python and Wolfram without as much overhead.  In it's simplest form, one can open a connection, interact with it, and close it using the following example:

```
path = "e:\\Programs\\python27\\python"; (*insert OS-appropriate path \
to python*)
p = StartProcess[{path, "-i"}]; (*the'-i' argument is important*)
cmd = "print 'hello'"; (*or any valid python expression*)
Pause[1]; (* important!!! *)
WriteLine[p, cmd];
out = ReadString[p, EndOfBuffer]
KillProcess@p;
```

Pausing after the `StartProcess` call is important in order to avoid the `cmd` being sent to the python interpreter before it has finished loading.  A much shorter pause can be used on faster computers.

I've put together a short package to streamline python interactivity.  The version I've posted below also reads the python shell text (which is delivered on stderr) and prints that to the Message window if the `FrontEnd` is active or simply `Print`s it if the command line is being used.  It works nicely with simple commands `pcmd@"print 'hello'"` and I've had success with some sophisticated operations such as web scraping with [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  It coughs when trying to use something like Tkinter, but it just doesn't work as opposed to throwing some form of error, making it a bit difficult to debug.

```
BeginPackage["wlPython`"];

$pythonprocess = Null;
    $pythonpath = "e:\\Programs\\python27\\python";
$pythonpause = 0.250; (* Pause in seconds to receive error information *)
startPython::usage = "Starts the python process";
endPython::usage = "Ends the python process";
pcmd::usage = "issue a python command";


(* Check for FrontEnd and set as appropriate, can be overridden *)
$pyfrontend = $FrontEnd=!=Null;

Begin["`Private`"];

Clear[startPython]
startPython[path_:$pythonpath]:=Module[{err},
     $pythonprocess = StartProcess[{path,"-i"}];
    wlPython`pyerrcheck[];
    $pythonprocess 
]

Clear[endPython]
endPython[process_:Unevaluated@$pythonprocess]:=Module[{},
    KillProcess@Evaluate@process;
    NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[],
    Cell[RawBoxes@ToBoxes["Python process ended",TraditionalForm],"Output"]];
]

Clear[pcmd]
pcmd[cmd_String,process_:Unevaluated@$pythonprocess]:=Module[{status,err,out,p},
    p = Evaluate[process];
    status = ProcessStatus[p];
    If[status=="Running",
    WriteLine[p,cmd];
    wlPython`pyerrcheck[];
    out = ReadString[p,EndOfBuffer]
    ];
    out
]

Clear[pyerrcheck]
pyerrcheck[]:=Module[{err},
    Pause@$pythonpause;
     err = ReadString[ProcessConnection[$pythonprocess,"StandardError"],EndOfBuffer];
    If[$pyfrontend,
        NotebookWrite[MessagesNotebook[],
        Cell[RawBoxes@ToBoxes[err,TraditionalForm],"Output"]];,
        Print[err];
    ]

]

End[];

EndPackage[];
```

Comment: This (excellent and previously accepted) answer is [outdated as of 11.2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167962/37).

Answer (score 17):

Here is a more robust solution using `Process`:

```
Clear[runPython];
runPython::badCommand  ="Python code failed to run with message `StandardError`";
$pyimports="from random import randint
";
runPython[str_String, imports_:$pyimports] := Module[
    {pyscrpt = ToString[$pyimports<>str, CharacterEncoding->"ASCII"], file=CreateTemporary[], res},
    Export[file,pyscrpt,"Text"];
    res = RunProcess[{"/anaconda/bin/python",file}];
    DeleteFile[file];
    If[res["ExitCode"]!=0, 
        Return @ Failure["badCommand",<|"MessageTemplate" :> runPython::badCommand,"MessageParameters"-> <|"Message" -> res["StandardError"]|>|>],
        Return @ ImportString @ res["StandardOutput"]
    ]
]
```

[image]

I had to use anaconda's python executable - Mathematica was crashing the system's python runtime.

Comment: " Here is a more robust solution using `Process`:" More robust than what?

Comment: Than the original answer from @raxa...

Comment: did you mean to write `(...) ToString[imports<>str (...)` in the second line of the definition of the function? The way it is now the second argument of `runPython` is useless

Comment: This (excellent and previously accepted) answer is [outdated as of 11.2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167962/37).

Answer (score 9):

If all you want is to invoke Python scripts and use the output they generate in Mathematica, then simply

```
pythonOutput = Import["!python fullpathtoscript/your_scipt.py --some_opt arg arg ...", "String"];
```

is sufficient.

Comment: Commands like this don't work at all for me in Mathematica 10.0.1.

Comment: It works for me in Mathematica 10.0.2.0.

Comment: @ThomasH: Can you give me a specific example of something that works that I can try. It doesn't even work for me anymore (10.0.2.0).

Comment: For a MWE, I made a file in my home directory called test.py containing "print('hello world')", then in Mathematica (also pointed at my home directory by default), 'Import["!python test.py","String"]' produces the string "hello world". I have a simple but slightly more complicated example I can point you to on github if you'd like.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach that works on Mac OS X or unix-like systems *without the need to explicitly create any temp directory*:

```
code = "print \\\"hello, starting\\\"
for i in [1,2,3]:
\t print i*i
 "

(* ==> 
"print \\\"hello, starting\\\" 
for i in [1,2,3]:
     print i*i
"
*)


RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", 
 "printf \"" <> code <> "\" | python
  exit
  "]

(* ==>
"hello, starting
1
4
9
"
*)
```

First, I define the string containing the Python code. I included a test message to illustrate how you have to escape the quotation marks using `\\\"` inside the string, because it's going to be passed into a `printf` command on the shell command line. THat `printf` is subsequently piped into `python`. Note that I *didn't* have to specify the path because it's found from the `SystemShell` environment.

The interaction with *Mathematica* takes place via `RunProcess`, and the standard output of the Python script is directly captured into *Mathematica*. Again, it's not necessary to bother with any temporary files in this approach.

Comment: Can you contrast this with the [`Import` approach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41510/37)? Is it just that it avoids using an existing script? FWIW, I'd never write the Python code in the *Mathematica* environment: the code editing tools are just too poor.

Comment: Also, can you show how it would work with an existing script?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Yes, my main point is to have the script and everything it needs completely inside *Mathematica*. If you already have an existing script outside *Mathematica*, then it's not a real two-way interaction, I'd say. But what to do with an existing script specifically would depend on the application. I can't think of anything general to say about that, except that it would be possible, e.g., to pass arguments to it using my approach. An important advantage of my approach is, however, that it makes the entire process *portable*: you can email the notebook without attachments.

Comment: Yes; also, it looks like the approach I had no longer works.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work for me at all either. I get nothing. And —weirdly — after executing it I can't quite the front end.

Comment: Oh well, that's just a formatting error when I manually tried to put the python string into a form that looks right in the code cell above. One extra space crept in, and that kills python. I fixed it. If it still doesn't work, it could be dependent on the OS and version of *Mathematica*. This `RunProcess` command doesn't work in earlier versions... by the way, another way of interacting with python is through the clipboard on Mac. But I don't know what your actual goal is, so I'll skip that for now.

Answer (score 4):

There's a "Python link" called [Pythonika](http://code.google.com/p/pythonika/).  I have used it briefly and it works.

What it does:

- translates basic data types, including arbitrary size integers, to/from Python
- makes it possible to implement functions in Python and call them from Mathematica

It does not provide any means to work with classes directly.  Also, the implementation is rather hackish using unsafe practices (e.g. symbols are not localized to a context, and this has bitten me).  To implement a link properly it would take *lot more* work.

I made a few basic fixes (e.g. using contexts), but I haven't used the thing in a long time.  Contact me if you want the fixes.

Comment: Does nt compile and does nt work.

Comment: Correct, it is deprecated and seems no longer maintained...

Comment: Hi, @Szabolcs, is there librarylink way use of python in Mathematica?

Comment: @matheorem There's no simple way.  LibraryLink or MathLink won't solve the problem of transferring and converting data structures between Python and Mathematica.  Someone would have to think about how that conversion should work and implement it *on top of LibraryLink or MathLink*.  (Actually the right choice is MathLink here in my opinion.)  That is a job that would take several weeks of full time work, even for a simple version.  I don't know who has time for that.

Comment: @Szabolcs If there is no librarylink for python, then with Pythonika you mentioned, is it possible to write python function that exploit power of numy and scipy, and calling it in Mathematica? How efficient is that?

Comment: @matheorem Sorry, this is 3.5 yr old answer and even then I said "I haven't used the thing in a long time".  I don't remember.  I wouldn't bother with Pythonika, as I remember it had a not very flexible design and no direct support for numpy.  A proper Python link would take a lot more work to put together.  Maybe you can write to Wolfram and suggest they create a Python link.  If there are many requests, they may do it.

Comment: @matheorem You can tell them what you want to use it for and point out that MATLAB has had a rather flexible Python link for quite a few versions.  Python functions and classes can be used quite directly with it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah, sorry, I didn't notice the date. Thank you so much for your answer : )

Comment: @matheorem Or if you want to create such a link yourself, then I suggest starting with exposing the MathLink (not LibraryLink!) API to Python.  Then you will have a nice and easy to use interprocess communication solution between M and Py.  You can write the rest of the link in these two high level langauges.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ok, I'll try to write some suggestions to wolfram support about this: )

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm developing a brand new [PyWSTP](https://github.com/khaotik/PyWSTP). Currently I'm having some [issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180706/how-to-send-packed-array-from-math-kernel-to-3rd-party-app-via-wstp) dealing with packed arrays.