# Any Progress with a Python MathLink?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I just want to asking if there any progress to connect Python with Mathematica Version 10 as Java or C, I mean a MathLink. I've been looking for a alternatives but I couldn't find it.

Thanks,

Comment: AFAIK there are no plans by WRI to provide a python link as an integral part of Mathematica like MathLink, JLink or NETLink. But a google search with Mathematica and python returns several existing projects/possibilities doing what you ask for, some even dicussed on this site. Have you tried these or are they not working for you?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15647/12

Comment: You could always suggest it to support at wolfram.com.  I guess the more users ask for it, the more likely we'll get it.  You might mention that MATLAB received some deep Python integration in its latest release (R2014b).