# Problem calling Python scripts from Mathematica

Tags: import, mac-os-x, command-line, python

so I'm running into a strange problem using `Import[]` to import the output of a python 3.6 script.

I have a script `my_script.py` which just contains `print('Hello, World!')`.

If from within Mathematica I pass

`pythonOutput = Import["!python my_script.py", "String"]`

I get the expected

`Hello, world!`

However, I am on Mac OS where the default installation of python is python 2.7 and so if I want to run my code in python 3.x in the terminal I would have to say

`python3 my_script.py` (which works fine)

However, when I modify my Mathematica code to say

`pythonOutput = Import["!python3 my_script.py", "String"]`

I get no output! Does anyone know why this might be the case? The command `python3 my_script.py` works perfectly fine from the terminal but not within an Import statement.

---

I have also tried every suggestion from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15647/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-from-within-mathematica/) and none of them work with the python3 command.

Comment: Does your python script literally contain 'print(Hello, World!)' without quotation marks? With quotation marks, it works using both python and python3 on linux.

Comment: No, my python script did not have the outer quotation marks. I tried adding the quotation marks and now it doesn't work with python 2 or 3

Comment: Sorry, that was probably confusing. I meant: Did you write print(Hello, World!) or print('Hello, World!')?

Comment: Oh I see, yes I did have the quotes I just mistype in my question.

Comment: use the full path name to python3

Comment: Or check `Environment["PATH"]`. Generally the python3 binary lives at /usr/local/bin/python3. In Mathematica I have `Environment["PATH"]` being "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin". Furthermore `RunProcess[{"python3", ExpandFileName@"~/Desktop/my_script.py"}, ProcessEnvironment -> <|  "PATH" -> "/usr/local/bin:" <> Environment["PATH"] |>]` works but sans `ProcessEnvironment` it fails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the path permanently available to *Mathematica* (frontend) and all other applications, first find out the location of your desired `python3` executable (e.g. from `which python3` in the Terminal), and then add this to the `path` variable that is set for all applications when the user logs in. Let's say the executable is in `/usr/local/bin` as @b3m2a1 mentioned in the comment to your question (**it may be somewhere else!**). Then do the following (in Terminal):

```
sudo launchctl config user path /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

The last four locations are the default entries, and I prepended the new location to that list (separated by `:`). To make this take effect, you have to restart the computer.

Comment: This worked! Thanks!