# How can I make images in the cell auto-adjust to some fixed-size

Tags: front-end, image

There is one `auto-adjust` item in the right-click menu of image in cell.

And other related items are `actual size` and `magnification`.

Can we set some values for the `auto-adjust`? 
(the effect like `ImageResize[image,100]` by hand)

The image was interted/paste in the cell.

[image]

Comment: I guess you might be interested in `CellEvaluationFunction`.

Comment: @Silvia I'm not sure if that suit for Image, I'll try that. If somewhere we can edit the value of `auto-adjust`, that would be the simplest way.

Comment: @Silvia fine:) `CellPrint[ExpressionCell[Rasterize@x,"Input",CellEvaluationFunction->(ImageCrop@ImagePad[ImageResize[ToExpression[#],100],20]&)]]`

Comment: hmm.. I didn't see difference between you example and that without the `CellEvaluationFunction` options.

Comment: @Silvia Evaluate the output cell will generate the effect, or make it one function,or button,This is one old post might related. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25700/is-it-possible-to-import-urls-not-type
Yeah, seems I still need one function to call the cell.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood your purpose.. Then I think you could try `$Post`, or make the output cell a dynamic thing.

Comment: What scaling do you want?  Do you want images both larger and smaller than your fixed size to be displayed at that fixed size, or only in one direction?  Also, you might find [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8592/121) relevant, though it is not an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Best is scaling determined by width. For example, fixed width  is 1000, then image whose width is less that 1000 will keep the actual size, and image whose width is 1200 will be adjusted to 1000, the ratio width/height is the same to that of the original image.

Answer (score 1):

Based on:

> Best is scaling determined by width. For example, fixed width is 1000, then image whose width is less that 1000 will keep the actual size, and image whose width is 1200 will be adjusted to 1000, the ratio width/height is the same to that of the original image.

I believe you may use simply:

```
$PrePrint = # /. i_Image :> Image[i, ImageSize -> 777] &;
```

This way images in output are automatically scaled to a fixed width (here 777), and only output is affected.  That is, if you define:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
```

The data assigned to `img` is unchanged, but the output is displayed at the width specified.  (If you copy and paste the output the the fixed size is included in that object.)

Comment: This works, but it looks only affect on images in output cells, and I'd like it affect image in Input Style cells or Text Style cells.

Comment: @HyperGroups I don't know about that.  Would it be an acceptable solution to programmatically process the Notebook to set image sizes throughout?  I know that's not ideal, but if no one has a better idea...

Comment: ok, of course,welcome to add some acceptable solutions.