# Summation matrix

Tags: matrix

I have problem with summation when it is in matrices. I want to make mathematica compute this:

[image]

Large X I have added dataset for as well as e. Would anyone be able to show me how to compute this in mathematica.

Due to comments Ill explain a bit more, X' is Transpose[X] so yes it would be a 2 by 2 matrix.

```
X= {{20.08, 1}, {19.78, 1}, {19.86, 1}, {19.4, 1}, {19.66, 1}, {19.32, 
  1}, {18.99, 1}, {19.29, 1}, {19.43, 1}, {19.52, 1}, {20.07, 
  1}, {20.13, 1}, {20.02, 1}, {19.9, 1}, {20.11, 1}, {20.44, 
  1}, {20.37, 1}, {20.31, 1}, {19.7, 1}, {20.12, 1}, {19.63, 
  1}, {19.76, 1}, {19.34, 1}, {19.66, 1}, {19.85, 1}, {20.32, 
  1}, {20.5, 1}, {20.9, 1}, {21.21, 1}, {21.15, 1}, {21.18, 
  1}, {21.02, 1}, {21.29, 1}, {20.92, 1}, {20.83, 1}, {21.22, 
  1}, {20.73, 1}, {20.76, 1}, {21.16, 1}, {21.31, 1}, {21.94, 
  1}, {22.7, 1}, {22.95, 1}, {22.8, 1}, {22.7, 1}, {22.9, 1}, {22.6, 
  1}, {22.4, 1}, {22.34, 1}, {22.43, 1}, {22.07, 1}, {22.01, 
  1}, {22.17, 1}, {22.1, 1}, {22.86, 1}, {23.26, 1}, {23.38, 
  1}, {23.59, 1}, {23.59, 1}, {23.53, 1}, {23.5, 1}, {23.78, 
  1}, {23.38, 1}, {23.52, 1}, {23.3, 1}, {23.48, 1}, {23.83, 
  1}, {24.2, 1}, {24.49, 1}, {24.69, 1}, {23.98, 1}, {23.79, 
  1}, {23.7, 1}, {23.26, 1}, {23.47, 1}, {23.95, 1}, {24.38, 
  1}, {24.75, 1}, {25.2, 1}, {24.68, 1}, {24.43, 1}, {24.73, 
  1}, {24.3, 1}, {24.97, 1}, {25.07, 1}, {25.17, 1}, {26.07, 
  1}, {26.41, 1}, {26.24, 1}, {26.83, 1}, {26.39, 1}, {26.64, 
  1}, {27.34, 1}, {26.58, 1}, {26.52, 1}, {26.58, 1}, {27., 
  1}, {26.54, 1}, {26.02, 1}, {26.33, 1}, {26.07, 1}, {25.81, 
  1}, {26.33, 1}, {26.3, 1}, {26.39, 1}, {26.26, 1}, {25.75, 
  1}, {26.21, 1}, {27.04, 1}, {26.74, 1}, {26.4, 1}, {25.89, 
  1}, {26.37, 1}, {26.28, 1}, {26.54, 1}, {26.66, 1}, {26.24, 
  1}, {25.35, 1}, {25.19, 1}, {24.07, 1}, {24.96, 1}, {25.29, 
  1}, {25.47, 1}, {25.13, 1}, {25.24, 1}, {24.99, 1}, {25.59, 
  1}, {25.68, 1}, {25.53, 1}, {26.68, 1}, {26.56, 1}, {27.04, 
  1}, {27.23, 1}, {27.34, 1}, {26.88, 1}, {29.66, 1}, {29.66, 
  1}, {29.11, 1}, {27.86, 1}, {27.36, 1}, {27.84, 1}, {28.27, 
  1}, {28.11, 1}, {27.93, 1}, {28.05, 1}, {28.09, 1}, {27.96, 
  1}, {27.65, 1}, {27.67, 1}, {27.32, 1}, {27.39, 1}, {27.48, 
  1}, {27.68, 1}, {28.35, 1}, {28.34, 1}, {28.05, 1}, {27.14, 
  1}, {27.32, 1}, {26.91, 1}, {27.12, 1}, {27.06, 1}, {27.9, 
  1}, {27.99, 1}, {27.7, 1}, {27., 1}, {27.11, 1}, {27.3, 1}, {27.12, 
  1}, {27.78, 1}, {28.07, 1}, {28.23, 1}, {28.17, 1}, {29.24, 
  1}, {29.48, 1}, {29.19, 1}, {29.65, 1}, {29.26, 1}, {29.62, 
  1}, {30., 1}, {30.44, 1}, {31.03, 1}, {30.93, 1}, {30.26, 
  1}, {31.27, 1}, {31.34, 1}, {32.75, 1}, {33.55, 1}, {33.17, 
  1}, {34.31, 1}, {34.14, 1}, {33.88, 1}, {34.89, 1}, {34.14, 
  1}, {32.93, 1}, {33.01, 1}, {33.87, 1}, {34.15, 1}, {34., 
  1}, {33.38, 1}, {33.09, 1}, {32.74, 1}, {33.43, 1}, {34.06, 
  1}, {33.94, 1}, {33.1, 1}, {33.08, 1}, {32.25, 1}, {32.35, 
  1}, {33.17, 1}, {32.57, 1}, {32.94, 1}, {33.18, 1}, {33.19, 
  1}, {32.97, 1}, {32.88, 1}, {32.11, 1}, {33.12, 1}, {33.82, 
  1}, {34.07, 1}, {35.1, 1}, {35.69, 1}, {35.47, 1}, {34.98, 
  1}, {34.63, 1}, {35.62, 1}, {36.3, 1}, {36.49, 1}, {36.29, 
  1}, {36.64, 1}, {36.96, 1}, {36.98, 1}, {37.01, 1}, {36.56, 
  1}, {38.13, 1}, {38.87, 1}, {38.86, 1}, {38.87, 1}, {40.22, 
  1}, {39.16, 1}, {39.35, 1}, {39.73, 1}, {39.73, 1}, {39.51, 
  1}, {40.04, 1}, {40.2, 1}, {40.12, 1}, {40.77, 1}, {40.85, 
  1}, {40.65, 1}}



    e={-39.5086, -34.3476, -21.3119, -17.2624, -22.8212, -12.6281, \
-4.05305, -10.284, -29.2365, -28.9788, -47.4106, -52.2288, -57.3004, \
-57.044, -21.7327, -14.2378, -13.6716, -15.6634, -3.07337, -9.56075, \
0.0428573, 17.8984, 7.95581, 9.61876, 11.0461, 7.3986, 15.974, \
6.7027, 0.0836829, 3.19188, 7.67778, 15.2763, 24.9694, 16.4266, \
20.9189, 18.9357, 17.7393, 16.6252, 19.9538, 19.0034, 14.0373, \
17.3368, 30.486, 25.6365, 28.4368, 24.1961, 32.2371, 28.1878, 26.836, \
21.6437, 20.0929, 14.5311, 15.5325, 20.0288, 4.56828, -2.70303, \
-5.26942, -5.80811, -15.5681, -23.0899, -15.6158, -8.19073, -8.70942, \
-22.0519, -30.5952, -41.6398, -44.3709, -37.6881, -42.0611, -45.5617, \
-42.4614, -28.0188, -37.4065, -47.103, -16.4617, -23.8073, -22.8127, \
-23.1099, -34.5714, -34.0337, -12.4429, -11.6738, -9.01844, -10.4266, \
4.10304, 18.3527, -0.190233, 10.8367, 11.3732, 10.7993, 15.0527, \
20.6719, 38.3996, 38.3901, 44.6483, 43.0501, 34.8527, 24.5722, \
26.1599, 11.7909, 23.8498, 14.9986, 9.23092, 10.165, 5.15272, \
-1.32286, 7.33681, 5.00731, 6.98059, 22.2116, 17.1747, 17.4044, \
14.8388, 14.3011, 21.4022, 33.8758, 40.5732, 38.6981, 37.4166, \
43.9763, 26.3214, 28.5563, 29.1317, 37.8048, 43.5765, 41.9573, \
36.5953, 42.233, 56.2035, 38.1798, 40.8262, 47.4906, 47.248, 47.1996, \
49.3891, 4.39601, -3.47399, -8.86219, 24.9919, 25.9935, 17.508, \
-4.48744, -4.30891, -4.54432, 2.20928, -1.59285, 16.9316, 24.1806, \
22.2945, 19.3957, 12.3694, 12.9571, 7.54649, -7.9417, -12.0437, \
-18.9007, -14.6697, -20.2643, -5.04498, -8.59367, -3.73548, -12.6302, \
-17.5525, -16.7896, -21.9673, -25.3056, -21.4283, -27.1137, -24.0638, \
-17.3968, -11.9953, -11.0271, -19.4666, -22.6394, -10.5365, -20.936, \
-18.7627, -25.7619, -33.4171, -23.1605, -37.4145, -31.1141, -37.136, \
-52.7573, -63.4735, -84.8161, -99.2387, -93.7135, -100.639, -96.9627, \
-104.754, -124.455, -119.213, -112.161, -111.235, -112.446, -113.121, \
-106.63, -90.9322, -70.3292, -74.0381, 37.6777, 19.6116, 25.208, \
62.8927, 57.3488, 60.1155, 58.3352, 66.6165, 70.2785, 64.5913, \
57.2585, 56.1704, 55.0572, 57.7095, 55.078, 47.1967, 30.6944, \
27.9336, 32.3462, 25.7823, 27.589, 33.3226, 32.5037, 13.9685, \
14.9823, 9.79964, 27.0003, 33.9492, 33.5921, 29.756, 24.1719, \
30.0634, 10.1723, -2.36215, 10.3259, 18.4378, 3.62343, 13.0049, \
2.67227, -12.503, -0.312969, 0.043751, 6.55802, 5.49949, 21.1638, \
25.3716, 20.8474, 29.628}
```

I have added the explanation from the book:

[image]

Comment: is $X'$ supposed to be the transpose of $X$? Then $X'X$ is just a 2 by 2 matrix. What is $N$ in there? You can say few words to explain the symbols used.

Comment: That is correct it is just the transpose.

Comment: But then, the result is a matrix. Yet, you say there is a linear sum there. This does not add up. How can sum[x x',{1,N}] be a sum over a matrix? a matrix is 2D not 1D. May be someone better than me in math can figure it out.

Comment: Nope, everything in there is taken straight out of textbook. Should be correct! It is also given proof in the textbook, however did not think it was any reason to post it because I am only interested in how to make mathematica due the calculation.

Comment: I could add the "proof" if that makes a difference? Could add the explanation, could be that I have misunderstood!

Comment: If I give you a matrix, which is 5 by 5. How can you operate on it, using one index?  This makes no sense to me. A Matrix is not a vector. It needs 2 indices, not one. Unless you give another information, such as an implied ordering, of you have flattened it, or such. But you are not giving this information. But what do I know. I am not a math major.

Comment: You are probably right, I will add the explenation from the textbook, might be the I have misunderstood what X looks like.

Comment: I have added the explanation now might very well be the case that I am wrong. But at least you are able to verify it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Please beware that this is NOT optimized. I just wrote down the formulas for easy understanding:

```
m =  SparseArray[{p_, q_} :> Sum[x[[i, p]] x[[i, q]], {i, Length@x}], {2, 2 }];
me = SparseArray[{p_, q_} :> Sum[e[[i]]^2 x[[i, p]] x[[i, q]], {i, Length@x}], {2, 2}];
mi = Inverse[m];
(v = mi.me.mi) // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.187057 & -4.58584 \\
 -4.58584 & 116.389 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Would you be able to optimize it?

Comment: @ALEXANDER I don't think it will serve any purpose, since Mathematica already has its own least squares algorithms implemented

Comment: But will the least square in mathematica be able to create newey west standard errors and white standard errors?

Comment: @ALEXANDER If you have  heteroskedasticity, take a look at ARCH and GARCH in the docs

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to handle it with Newey west standard errors or white standard errors, I am aware of ARCH and GARCH.

Comment: @ALEXANDER use the R interface and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136870/r-standard-errors

Comment: Ive never used R and a combination of R and mathematica, so I am not sure if that would help me since I want to be able to compute it in Mathematica. But thank you for the help.

Comment: @ALEXANDER You can! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16657/193