# Mathematica and Python integration?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to run Python from within Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15647/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-from-within-mathematica)

I do see the latest version has R-link:

http://www.wolfram.co.uk/mathematica/new-in-9/built-in-integration-with-r/

Is it possible to integrate with Python as I have not seen it before? I have some codes in Python that I want to translate into Mathematica, can someone point out with a few simple examples of Importing, Exporting, simple routines to help me get going?

Or is it not yet a feature as of version 9?

Comment: I think it is possible, but to my knowledge this has not been done yet, at least at the same level of intergation as with R. Writing a general link with Python is likely to be a lot of work. But I agree that it would be nice to have it.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but [pythonika](http://code.google.com/p/pythonika/) might be worth a look.

Comment: Closely related: [Calling IronPython code from Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1894/245)