# Call Haskell from Mathematica and return the results inside Mathematica

Tags: programming, interoperability

I would like to learn Haskell using Mathematica's environment.

I know there is the RLink protocol. Is there a similar protocol for Haskell?

Comment: There is [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mathlink).

Comment: A very basic integration with Haskell is described as part of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18572/142).

Comment: Thank you for the links above. I will try them.